# Как воспроизвести ILIKE в Django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

В Django как ILIKE работают 2 лукапа - 'iexact' и 'icontains'. Первый создает запросы вида `ILIKE 'my query'`, а второй `ILIKE '%my query%'`.

Вопрос - как с помощью Django ORM сделать запрос `ILIKE '%my%query%'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Встроенной возможности нет, но можно определить пользовательский [lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-lookups/):

```
from django.db.models import Lookup
from django.db.models.fields import Field

@Field.register_lookup
class ILikeLookup(Lookup):
    lookup_name = 'ilike'

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        params = lhs_params + rhs_params
        return '%s ILIKE %s' % (lhs, rhs), params
```

После этого его можно использовать так:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(somefield__ilike='%my%query%')
```